# UniWebView message throttling/collision?

Tags: javascript, c#, uniwebview

I have the following listener setup in my Unity scene:

```
ui.OnMessageReceived += (view, message) => {
    var path = message.Path;
    var action = message.Args ["action"];
    if (path == "app") {
        if (action == "log") {
            Debug.Log ("[W] " + message.Args ["text"]);
        }
    }   
};
```

And in my web view I have this log function:

```
log: function(m) {
    window.location.href = 'uniwebview://app?action=log&text=' + m;
}
```

When I execute the following code, the only output that shows up in logcat are tests 5 and E:

```
app.log("Echo Test (1)");
app.log("Echo Test (2)");
app.log("Echo Test (3)");
app.log("Echo Test (4)");
app.log("Echo Test (5)");
setTimeout(function() {
    app.log("Echo Test (A)");
    app.log("Echo Test (B)");
    app.log("Echo Test (C)");
    app.log("Echo Test (D)");
    app.log("Echo Test (E)");
}, 500);
```

> ```
> 08-16 13:55:20.229 13860 13881 I Unity   : [W] Echo Test (5)
> 08-16 13:55:20.693 13860 13881 I Unity   : [W] Echo Test (E)
> ```

What is causing this and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the URL doesn't get time to post to your listener. Your instantly changing the address so it's not executing. You added the timeout which is a sensible thing to do, I suggest you creating a function that waits after each log.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709893/two-urls-in-function-using-window-location-href) is another post having a similar issue that required a time out.

```
log: function(m) {
  setTimeout(function(){
     window.location.href = 'uniwebview://app?action=log&text=' + m;
  },500 
}
```

I haven't tested this but if you didn't want to use a timer with 500 milliseconds you could probably check to see if the page has finished loading before you execute the next request

```
var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
        init();
    }
}, 10);
```